# iCloud not work after update

Tags: objective-c, ios, itunes, icloud

At the stage of testing applications iCloud works fine. But after the application checks for updates from apple and download from itunes, icloud is not working, then there is a line

`NSURL * returnedURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil];`

returns nil.

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your containers are listed in the `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers` entitlement?

[Apple's Documentation on NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` mentions:

> If you specify nil, this method returns the first container listed in the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement.